# Homotopy invariance of unordered configuration spaces of manifolds

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $C(k,M)$ be the $k$-points unordered configuration space of connected manifold $M.$ In general, it is clear that $C(k,M)$ is not homotopy invariant of $M.$ Assume $M$ and $N$ are not homotopy equivalent manifolds. Is it true or not that $C(k,M)$ and $C(k,N)$ are not homotopy equivalent?

Comment: It is not actually easy to show that $C(k,M)$ is not a homotopy invariant of manifolds. Indeed, I believe it is unknown whether or not it is for simply connected manifolds. It is known (surprisingly) that it is an invariant of the rational homotopy type of simply connected manifolds. I suspect that the answer to your question is unknown in general, but it might have answers if you know things like the cohomology rings of $M$ and $N$ are nonisomorphic.

Comment: @Connor:  are you assuming the manifolds are closed?  Otherwise, I agree with the OP that $C(k,M)$ is obviously not a homotopy invariant:  all Euclidean spaces are contractible, while $C(2,\mathbb{R}^n)$ has the homotoy type of $S^{n-1}$.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Configuration spaces are most naturally compared only in the same dimension manifold. In this case, open manifolds are actually interesting because there are embeddings of manifolds that are homotopy equivalences but not homeomorphisms. For such an embedding, it actually induces a homotopy equivalence on configuration spaces so, for example, all contractible manifolds have the same configuration space (up to homotopy) as $\mathbb{R}^n$ where n is the dimension.

Comment: @Conner:  That's really interesting - I know next to nothing about configuration spaces.